# Open two sessions in the same browser using virtualhosts with apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, authentication

My two hosts uses the Apache authentication, the first authentication with my **virtualhost1** is fine but when I open a new tab for the the second host(**virtualhost2**), the first is disconnected(**virtualhost1**).

Here is a snippet of my configuration file (default-ssl)

```
    <Proxy *>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass   /virtualhost1/       https://virtualhost1:443/
    ProxyPassReverse /virtualhost1/  https://virtualhost1:443/

    ProxyPass   /virtualhost2/      https://localhost:443/
    ProxyPassReverse /virtualhost2/  https://localhost:443/


    <Location /virtualhost1/>
         SetEnv Proxy-Chain-Auth On
     </Location>
```

Is there a configuration that allows me to do that with apache2 in the same browser, to allow multiple sessions ?

P.S : I can solve that with a private window.

Comment: -1 Those aren't VirutalHosts... What you're asking is possible and easy. What you're doing isn't what you're asking and isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. I'm not sure what exactly what you're attempting to accomplish, but with the same browser you cannot have two different authenticated sessions (assuming you're using Basic Auth or some variation).

The reason private works is because it doesn't expose your session cookies from your normal sessions. You'd need an extension for your browser that can switch sessions (for example, [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) for Firefox.